# WSO2 IS How to get oauth2 token using the user certificate

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need to obtain oauth2 token using the user certificate in WSO2 IS 5.9, where I have an OAuth2 SP configured. Is it possible to obtain a oauth2 token just with the certificate and using no password?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use the X509 authenticator as described in this [documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/x509certificate-authenticator/). Then you can use this authenticator in your Service Provider's Local and Outbound Authentication configurations.

Comment: This is for wso2 is 5.10. Do you have any links for the 5.9?

Comment: I couldn't find the 5.9.0 version. But shouldn't be any different from this. Please refer to this one.